# Cast to integral type or other type cannot appear in a constant expression

Tags: c++

Ideone testcase: http://ideone.com/lzepF

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <set>

#include <stdint.h>

template <typename T> std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, T const& x);
template <typename T> std::istream& read(std::istream& is, T& x);

template <typename T, typename U> std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, std::pair<T, U> const& rh);
template <typename T, typename U> std::istream& read(std::istream& is, std::pair<T, U>& rh);

template <typename T> std::ostream& writeContainer(std::ostream& os, T const& rh);

template <typename T, typename U> std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, std::map<T, U> const& rh);
template <typename T, typename U> std::istream& read(std::istream& is, std::map<T, U> rh);

template <typename T> std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& rh);
template <typename T> std::istream& read(std::istream& is, std::vector<T>& rh);

template <typename T>
std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, T const& x){
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>(), "That's a pointer, you probably don't want to write that");
    static_assert(std::is_pod<T>(), "That's not a POD: can't write it");
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&x), sizeof(T));
    return os;
}

template <typename T>
std::istream& read(std::istream& is, T& x){
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>(), "That's a pointer, you probably don't want to read that");
    static_assert(std::is_pod<T>(), "That's not a POD: can't read it");
    is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x), sizeof(T));
    return is;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, std::pair<T, U> const& rh){
    write(os, rh.first);
    write(os, rh.second);
    return os;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
std::istream& read(std::istream& is, std::pair<T, U>& rh){
    read(is, rh.first);
    read(is, rh.second);
    return is;
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& writeContainer(std::ostream& os, T const& rh){
    uint32_t size = std::distance(rh.begin(), rh.end());
    write(os, size);

    for(auto it = rh.begin(); it != rh.end(); ++it){
        write(os, *it);
    }

    return os;
}

template <typename T>
std::istream& readContainer(std::istream& is, T& rh){
    uint32_t size;
    read(is, size);
    std::insert_iterator<T> it(rh, rh.end());

    for(uint32_t i=0; i<size; ++i) {
        typename T::value_type x;
        read(is, x);
        it = x;
    }
    return is;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, std::map<T, U> const& rh){
    return writeContainer(os, rh);
}

template <typename T, typename U>
std::istream& read(std::istream& is, std::map<T, U> rh){
    return readContainer(is, rh);
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& rh){
    return writeContainer(os, rh);
}

template <typename T>
std::istream& read(std::istream& is, std::vector<T>& rh){
    return readContainer(is, rh);
}

int main(){
    {
        std::stringstream s;
        std::vector<int> x = {0, 1, 2, 3};
        write(s, x);
    }

    {
        std::stringstream s;
        std::map<int, int> x = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}};
        write(s, x);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& write(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = unsigned int, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]':
prog.cpp:57:2:   instantiated from 'std::ostream& writeContainer(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = std::vector<int>, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
prog.cpp:92:30:   instantiated from 'std::ostream& write(std::ostream&, const std::vector<T>&) [with T = int, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
prog.cpp:104:13:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:29:11: error: a cast to a type other than an integral or enumeration type cannot appear in a constant-expression
prog.cpp:29:11: error: a cast to a type other than an integral or enumeration type cannot appear in a constant-expression
prog.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& write(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = int, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]':
prog.cpp:60:3:   instantiated from 'std::ostream& writeContainer(std::ostream&, const T&) [with T = std::vector<int>, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
prog.cpp:92:30:   instantiated from 'std::ostream& write(std::ostream&, const std::vector<T>&) [with T = int, std::ostream = std::basic_ostream<char>]'
prog.cpp:104:13:   instantiated from here
prog.cpp:29:11: error: a cast to a type other than an integral or enumeration type cannot appear in a constant-expression
prog.cpp:29:11: error: a cast to a type other than an integral or enumeration type cannot appear in a constant-expression
```

Since we have no line numbers, :( ,  it complains about the FIRST `write(s, x)`, and seems to me complain about the `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(const unsigned int*)` but I'm pretty sure that should be legal.

What's going wrong?

Comment: Instead of `std::is_pointer<T>()` etc., shouldn't it be `std::is_pointer<T>::value`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the `is_pod` and `is_pointer` incorrectly. You need to change it to the following:

```
    static_assert(!std::is_pointer<T>::value, "That's a pointer, you probably don't want to write that");
    static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "That's not a POD: can't write it");
```

You can test with this:

```
    write(std::cout, 1);
    int *p = 0;
    write(std::cout, p);
```

Answer (score 1):

**C++03 Standard  5.19 "Constant expressions", Para 1** states:

> In several places, C++ requires expressions that evaluate to an integral or enumeration constant: as array bounds (8.3.4, 5.3.4), as case expressions (6.4.2), as bit-field lengths (9.6), as enumerator initializers (7.2), as static member initializers (9.4.2), and as integral or enumeration non-type template arguments (14.3).
>
> *constant-expression: conditional-expression*
>
> An integral constant-expression can involve only literals (2.13), enumerators, const variables or static data members of integral or enumeration types initialized with constant expressions (8.5), non-type template parameters of integral or enumeration types, and sizeof expressions. Floating literals (2.13.3) can appear only if they are cast to integral or enumeration types. **Only type conversions to integral or enumeration types can be used.** In particular, except in sizeof expressions, functions, class objects, pointers, or references shall not be used, and assignment, increment, decrement, function-call, or comma operators shall not be used.

The code statements:

> static_assert(!std::is_pointer(), "That's a pointer, you probably don't want to write that");
> static_assert(std::is_pod(), "That's not a POD: can't write it");

break this rule and hence the compiler complains.

Comment: Is this still true for C++11? OP reports success with the original code on newer `g++`.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Let me look up C++11 draft and getback.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Yup, this is changed in C++11, The standard no longer imposes this constraint, Seems gcc has been quick enough to comply the C++11.